# Statecode for Salesorder created by Convertquotetosalesorder in the sdk

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm

What is the expected statecode for an salesorder created via the dynamics 365 sdk call convertquotetosalesorder?

Also, will an existing salesorder based on that quote affect the statecode of an additional salesorder created assuming that duplicate detection does not block the second creation?

I'm not finding any info in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this via code today. The Orders got created with StateCode of Active (0) and StatusCode of New (1).